# How can I pass NSNib.Name to a window controller in Swift/Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm having the hardest time wrapping my old brain around what's happened to Swift/Cocoa in the last year and a half. It started with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021371/windownibname-error-in-swift-cocoa/49021729#49021729) of learning that windowNibName is now a struct rather than a String, which @technerd thankfully solved for me in my MainWindowController class:

```
override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
    return NSNib.Name( "MainWindowController" )
}
```

But then, how to use?

This code in my AppDelegate class used to work:

```
var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    // Create a window controller with a XIB file of the same name
    let mainWindowController = mainWindowController()

    // Put the window of the window controller on screen
    mainWindowController.showWindow( self )

    // Set the property to point to the window controller
    self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController

}
```

But then I got a ton of errors with helpful solutions from Xcode that I happily followed starting with

> Variable used within its own initial value; use 'self.' to refer to
>   the variable

until I was left with:

```
var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    // Create a window controller with a XIB file of the same name
    let mainWindowController = self.mainWindowController

    // Put the window of the window controller on screen
    mainWindowController?.showWindow( self )

    // Set the property to point to the window controller
    self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController

}
```

Which doesn't work--it compiles just fine, but no window shows. It kind of makes sense, as I'm guessing that this new mainWindowController doesn't know what the passed one is. But tinker as I might, I can't get it to work. Any ideas would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up lowercase and uppercase notation. If you are using the same name for class and variable be careful how to write it, case sensitivity matters.

To initialize a class you have to use the uppercase name.

```
self.mainWindowController = MainWindowController()
mainWindowController?.showWindow( self )
```

Comment: Oh my, @vadian, I am an idiot. And here I thought that it was something new 